# Из бинарного файла запись выводится бесконечно

Tags: c++

с++
Мне нужно вывести информацию из бинарного файла на экран, но выводится только первая запись и, похоже, бесконечное количество раз

Найден человек, проживающий по адресу с номером телефона:
                   Petrov                Ivan                Ivanovich             Saratov         Positivnaya 5 1          9743877439

и так много раз. Как исправить, чтобы выводились все и по одному разу?

```
  void prosmotr(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Мало параметров\nPress any key");

        return;
    }
    FILE* fb = fopen(argv[1], "rb+");
    if (fb == NULL) {
        printf("Error: не удалось открыть двоичный файл %s\n",
            argv[1]);
        printf("Press ENTER");

        return;
    }
    TBook Book;
    int nr = 1, kol=0;
    nr = fread(&Book, sizeof(Book), 1, fb);
    while (nr == 1) {
        printf("Найден человек, проживающий по адресу с номером телефона:\n");
        printf("%25s%20s%25s%20s%20s%2d%2d%20s\n", Book.FIO.F,
            Book.FIO.I, Book.FIO.O, Book.ADDRESS.city, Book.ADDRESS.street, Book.ADDRESS.house, Book.ADDRESS.flat, Book.number);

        kol++;
    }
    if (kol == 0)
        printf("Данные не найдены\n");
    else
        printf("Всего найдено: %d\n", kol);
    fclose(fb);
    printf("Press any key to continue");
    getch();
    return;

}
```

Comment: Ну вы же в цикле `while (nr == 1) {` не читаете новые записи из файла, и просто выводите одну и ту же запись! В цикле только `printf` и никакого изменения `nr`! Кто будет читать другие записи? Простите, вы сами смотрели свой код? Или сразу бросились за помощью - там, где бросаться просто стыдно?

Comment: @Harry, Eсли можете- помогите, если нет не мешайте людям

Comment: @Kolibri  Я помог. Так, как я понимаю **помощь** - заставить человека думать,  а не разжевать и положить пережеванное в рот. Кстати, а почему вы не помогаете? *Не можете помочь - не мешайте другим* (с)

Comment: @Harry, Не стыдно не знать, стыдно не учиться․ Можно было помочь и сказать, что было легко, не сказать, бросаться за помощью просто стыдно 
Таким образом, людям будет стыдно просить о помощи, а именно цель этого сайта - получить помощь.

Comment: И да, кстати, если вам интересно, я не знала ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
int kol=0;
while (fread(&Book, sizeof(Book), 1, fb) == 1)
{
    printf("Найден человек, проживающий по адресу с номером телефона:\n");
    printf("%25s%20s%25s%20s%20s%2d%2d%20s\n", Book.FIO.F,
        Book.FIO.I, Book.FIO.O, Book.ADDRESS.city, Book.ADDRESS.street, Book.ADDRESS.house, Book.ADDRESS.flat, Book.number);
    kol++;
}
```